# Winforms DataGridView is adding two rows instead of one

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When I add data to a row in my DataGridView I want a blank row to be added. This occurs but when I focus on a field in the current row and enter no data, default values are populated for that row and the new row is populated with the default values as well.  Then another blank row is added as you can see from the animated gif I pasted below.

[image]

I wanted to see if anyone could help me determine what to do to prevent the blank row from being populated with default values as well as the current row. After leaving a field in the current row and not entering a value, it's okay for default values to populate that row but I don't want anything to populate the blank row.

I have pasted relevant code from the form class below. I tried to eliminate parts of the class that were not relevant to the question:

```
public partial class frmCharitableContributions : Form
{
    private readonly string connectionString = ConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString();
    private readonly BusinessLayer bl = new BusinessLayer();


    private void FrmCharitableContributions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PopulateDataGridView();
    }


    private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsCharitableContributions = bl.GetCharitableContributions(connectionString);

            CharitableContributionsDataGridView.DataSource = dsCharitableContributions.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Thrown in PopulateDataGridView: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void CharitableContributionsDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CharitableContributionsDataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = CharitableContributionsDataGridView.CurrentRow;

            bool isValid = ValidateFields(dgvRow);
            if (isValid)
            {
                bl.InsertOrUpdateCharitableContributions(connectionString, dgvRow);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(PopulateDataGridView));
        }
    }

    // This event will fire when a cell recognize editing
    private void CharitableContributionsDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        CharitableContributionsDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    // This event will fire when a cell recognizes the end of editing
    // Allow or deny adding a new row here based on conditions such as required fields being filled in or selected
    private void CharitableContributionsDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentRowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow dgvRow = CharitableContributionsDataGridView.Rows[currentRowIndex];
        if (dgvRow.Cells["cbxCharitableOrganizationName"].Value.ToString() != "")
        {

            if (CharitableContributionsDataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
            {


                bl.InsertOrUpdateCharitableContributions(connectionString, dgvRow);

                CharitableContributionsDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You turn off allowusertoaddrows only in the begincelledit event. Is it on before? if so why and what happens if you turn it off?

Comment: Are you actually calling `PopulateDataGridView` from `_CellValueChanged`, resetting the DataSource?

Comment: @TaW I tried turning AllowUserToAddRows off in the constructor, but when doing that there are no rows to edit in the grid. So then I tried to turn it off in the RowLeave event. That let me populate one row but not add any additional.

Comment: @Jimi Instead of just calling the PopulateDataGridView method from the CellValueChanged event I was using the BeginInvoke method to Invoke the PopulateDataGridView because I was getting an error that said Operation Not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentAddressCore function. In PopulateDataGridView I am setting the DataSource each time that method is called.

Comment: You can add a new row to the DataSource with just: `var dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable; dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());`. If you have stored the DataTable object, just use that. The new row will be immediately shown right after the one you just created.